# How can I make Vim position the cursor at the start of a tab character instead of the end?

Tags: cursor-movement, whitespace, tab-characters

Open an empty buffer and insert a tab character then exit to normal mode. When you place the cursor (normal mode) on the tab it will be at the right side of the whitespace. I'm looking for a way so the cursor will be at the left side of the whitespace instead. Thanks!

Comment: This has driven me nuts for years!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's only a clumsy workaround, but if you `:set list` the cursor will be positioned on the other "side" of the tab.

Comment: Thank you! You helped me look in the right place. `:set list listchars=tab:\ \ ` results in what I asked for. Now I just need to see if it's as useful as I thought!

Answer (score 6):

The cursor in normal mode is on the character not to either side. So you can do `i` and `a` to go to insert mode to the left or right of the tab respectively.

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more clear. This has nothing to do with insert mode. I use hard tabs and each hard tab takes up four spaces. When I move the cursor (normal mode) onto a hard tab character it ends up on the right-most column of the tab. I want it to be at the left-most column of the tab. This is purely a aesthetic issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just use command `:set listchars=tab:\ \  list`.

I intentionally put `list` in the end to preserve the space after last backslash in the `listchars` option value.